# Submit not working with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox

Simple jquery script:

```
$( "#action" ).submit(function( event )
 {
     if ($("#field_name").val() == 1 ){
         alert('1');
         return true;}
         else {
             alert('no');
         return false;}
  });
```

This script work with FF but nothing happens on IE. How to validate/check form on IE?

Comment: use click instead of submit

Comment: What element type is `#action`?  And do you get any errors in the Console?

Comment: @RichieHindle form ID

Comment: Show HTML related to `action`

Comment: This type of example really needs the HTML as well. Preferably all in a JSFiddle. :)

Comment: Works on IE 7,8, and 9 for me.  1. Are you wrapping it in an onready function?  2. What version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3gzdL/ i put on Fiddle

Comment: @RichardB IE 9  but i can change to 8 or 7

Comment: @user3747585: That fiddle has broken HTML. Your version works when corrected: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/y4y83/1/

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/y4y83/1/

### DOM Ready?

The most likely cause is not wrapping your jQuery in a DOM ready event.

```
$(function () {
    $("#action").submit(function (event) {
        if ($("#field_name").val() == 1) {
            alert('1');
            return true;
        } else {
            alert('no');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

`$(function () {` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){`

Without that, the browser load time will have an impact, depending on the jQuery code placement (not at end of body etc)

### Include JQuery?

*The sample JSFiddles provided in comments had broken HTML. not also none of them included jQuery. please ensure you are including jQuery correctly.*

Comment: @user3747585: Your JSFiddle has broken HTML (`head` tag contains the form and has no closing `>`)

Comment: @user3747585: You have not included JQuery on the left of JSFiddle :) It works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3gzdL/3/

Comment: This works fine in IE 9, 10 and "edge" mode: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3gzdL/3/

Comment: @so problem somewere in my IE ?

Comment: Sounds like it if that last JSFiddle is not working for you in IE. Nobody else is having a problem.

Comment: The fiddle works for me fine, too.  Sounds like your IE has a problem.  Does jquery's own demo work for you on IE?  http://api.jquery.com/submit/  If not, does any jquery work?

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the onSubmit event in the HTML form code ; which is working better on IE.

```
<form ... onSubmit="return checkForm();">
   // form
</form>    

<script>
    function checkForm(){
        // your function that should return true or false
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This should make no difference. Also unobtrusive jQuery coding usually requires not having inline code.